# Что такое ошибки времени исполнения?

Tags: c++, c

Расскажите пожалуйста, что такое ошибки времени исполнения? Когда они возникают? Если можно, то хотелось бы посмотреть на примерах кода на C/C++. И как их можно вызывать в системных вызовах linux ?

Comment: https://www.reactive-systems.com/c-runtime-errors.html

Comment: @andreymal спасибо)

Answer (score 4):

*Ошибки времени исполнения* (*runtime error*) — это любая ошибка возникающая при работе программы. т.е. когда говорят: «*этот код приводит к ошибки времени выполнения*» — это просто значит, что компиляция и линковка проходят без ошибок, но при запуске что-то идёт не так. Обычно подразумевается, что эта ошибка приводит к аварийному завершению программы, но, вообще говоря, может иметься в виду, и просто неверный результат.

*Ошибки времени выполнения* обычно противопоставляются *ошибкам времени компиляции* (*compile time errors*), которые, как очевидно из названия, происходят на этапе сборки ПО.